# Position absolute table safari / iOS

Tags: html, css, safari

I have the following code which work great on firefox but on safari the `tr` position relative is ignored and the `td` is placed relatively to the `.container` and not the `tr`

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

tr {
  position: relative;
}

td {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: what version of Safari are you trying with ?

Comment: @LarsNielsen I have the issue on safari mac 17.2.1 , iOS version 17.3.1 which is bundled to safari, and I also have the issue on Google Chrome on iOS with version 122.0.6261.89

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve here? Why would you need to position table cells absolute?

Comment: This is a old html code and I need to update the design only for mobile using media query. So I will keep my `table` with three cols on desktop but on mobile the second col is on top of the first and third col, for example it could be `<div class="col-12" /><div class="col-6" /><div class="col-6" />` with bootstrap 
But this is a huge heavy old code and I can not easily update the html structure

Comment: use a div inside td. Also use -webkit-position: relative; for safari

Answer (score 0):

Something like this isn't supposed to work on tables. Table rows or groups don't provide positioning or containment.

```
tr {
    position: relative;
}
span {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/dutchcelt/pen/GReoMWG